# How login node communicates with compute node in a slurm cluster?

Tags: python, slurm

I just start to use computing cluster which is running with Slurm Workload Manager. I'm curious about how the compute nodes communicate with the login node while computing, since the script about to run is stored in the login node along with other files that might be read by the script.

For example, in the working dictionary, a list of floats is stored in a format that can be loaded with `pickle`. The script I expect to run on a compute node is something looks like this:

```
import pickle
with open('data_list.db', 'rb') as source_file:
    data_list = pickle.load(source_file)

data_sum = sum(data_list)
print(data_sum)
```

If I submit this `example.py` script by bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --partition=the_partition
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=6
python example.py
```

What exactly is running on the login node and the compute node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slurm expects that the login node and compute node all have access to the same network filesystem (typically [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)) or parallel filesystem ([BeeGFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeeGFS), [Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)), etc.) so that every file can be read and written in any exported directory from any compute node.

Answer (score 0):

SLURM spawns your job on the compute nodes via the slurm control daemons, when your job starts it starts from you home directory unless you specify a path to a different file system (like /lustre). The login nodes and compute nodes should all see the same file systems but you generally cant run your programs on the login node.